# Apply changes instant after query

Tags: php, mysql

When the form is submitted a query runes and updates the background id after that it reloads itself. Now the problem is that i need to reload the page again to see the updated background.
So my question is : How do i apply changes instant after my query is done.

My form :

```
   <form id="myForm" method="get">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="span4 info1">
            <section class="widget">
               <img src="../bootstrap/img/thumb/0.jpg" width="auto" height="auto">
               <?php 
                  if ($selectedBg == '0') {
                    echo '<h2>Current one</h2>';
                  } 
               ?>
               <input type="radio" name="options[]" value="0" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();"/>Choose Background
            </section>
         </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

my query

```
<?php
    $checked = $_GET['options'];
    for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE blog_users SET background = '.$checked[$i].' WHERE username=?';
        $bg = $db->prepare($sql);
        $bg->execute(array($session->username));
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're open to SQL Injections.

Comment: Are the html and the php code all in the same file or seperate files?

Comment: What do you mean by "i need to reload the page again to see the updated background." When you submit the form, it will (or at least, it shoudl) reload the page by itself

Comment: Show all the code there are too many mysteries here. Too much code missing to give a sensible answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Its all on the same page. Also i mean when i submit the form it runs the query + a reload but i need to reload the page a second time to apply the changes + this is all the code. The form itself is allot bigger but it is 6 times the same span4 so thats why i did not post that

Comment: Use AJAX + jQuery + JSON

Comment: @JacobBrol So what element in your html shows the background color selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect to the same page after you're done processing the query,

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
exit;
```

That's what I'd do. Besides, this would prevent unnecessary form resubmissions.